# Why do white supremacists use the term "Anglo Saxon values"?

Tags: united-states, europe, racism

I heard on the news about a group called "America First" that supposedly wants to protect "Anglo-Saxon values". Other American and European nativists have also used that phrase.

Why the Anglo-Saxon part? Why not, say, "European values"? Is it because they want to exclude people like the Irish and others?

Comment: I don't want to name its founders because I don't want controversy

Comment: I’m not sure this is universal. I’ve seen white supremacists use “European values” and “western values” too. I don’t know that I’d put too much thought into the specifics, since they’re all euphemisms for “white people”, however that group chooses to define them

Comment: I wasn't saying it was. I wanted to focus on why they are picking on the Anglo-Saxon specifically.

Comment: I doubt people who identify with their German, Jewish, Irish, Italian... heritage would specifically want to protect Anglo-Saxon values.

Comment: @VladimirF: the Saxon in Anglo Saxon heritage, refers to Germanic heritage.  But it is indeed (in my opinion) a term meant to exclude Irish and Italian, as well as French and Polish heritage.

Comment: @VladimirF Stephen Miller?

Comment: Most of the answers to this question seem to be primarily opinion-based (at least so far). Lots of plausible-sounding speculation based on what people _think_ your stereotypical average white supremacist would believe, but very little supporting evidence.

Comment: There are so few actual white supremacists.  Why do we care what they think?

Comment: @acpilot Not so sure that's quite true. In any group of people, there are those willing to speak out, to differentiate themselves openly. They are the one's willing to take the heat for their beliefs. In something as ... devisive? ... as white supremacy, the ratio of those willing to speak up simply must be lower. So, a possible question to ask (not on topic, and probably opinion-based, so not going to do it) would be how many people (sheep) does each supremacist represent?

Comment: They may be vocal but they are few. Hand-wavey statements of "there just MUST be lots of them" is irresponsible.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The notion of 'Anglo-Saxon values' goes back to the days of British colonialism. One of the more common justifications of colonialism was that the British (Anglo-Saxon) culture was the pinnacle of societal achievement, something that had to be imposed on more 'primitive' races because they weren't sufficiently sophisticated to develop or appreciate it on their own. In that sense, pushing into an undeveloped region, establishing colonies, extracting resources, and coercing native populations into labor forces under British administration was morally acceptable because the British were exporting their superior social and cultural values to the benighted dark-skinned peoples of the world. The idea persisted in US slave culture — to wit, the occasionally-still-heard argument that US blacks should be happy about slavery because it brought them out of Africa into the more enlightened US — and has established itself as a tenet of US Right-wing ethnonationalist ideology.

Whenever you hear a reference of this sort to 'Anglo-Saxon values', understand that the speaker intends to convey an idealized (and almost certainly mythologized) image of 18th/19th century British colonialism, where dark-skinned peoples could not be trusted to rule themselves or participate in their own governance, but must be controlled, administered, educated, and uplifted by the 'perfected' Liberal culture of the British Isles. It isn't xenophobic as much as deeply (absurdly) arrogant and paternalistic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123406/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-why-do-white-supremacists-use-the-term-angl).

Answer (score 40):

Like most motivation questions, we can't answer definitively (unless the group in question have commented), but we can make some intelligent guesses.

"[Anglo-Saxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxons)" means the people descended from Germanic invaders of what is now England who then intermarried with the native Celts. The original Anglo-Saxons were not Nordic, but during the [Danelaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danelaw) there was also quite a lot of intermarriage between the invading Norse and the conquered Anglo-Saxons, and then there was the [Norman invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normandy) (the Normans were Norse men who settled in northern France).

If you squint and ignore the distinction between the original Anglo-Saxons and the influx of Nordic invaders, this makes "Anglo-Saxon" a close synonym for "[Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryanism)" as the term was defined by the Nazis: ancestry and culture that is Nordic and northern-European. The Nazis believed that Aryan culture and racial characteristics were superior to all others.

So the likely explanation is that they are using "Anglo-Saxon" as a dog-whistle code for "Aryan".

Comment: I don't think it's really a "dog whistle" to avoid using a term that has negative associations.  Is "undercover cop" a dog whistle for "secret police"?

Comment: @Acccumulation While avoiding terms that use negative associations are not necessarily [dog whistles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_whistle_(politics)), all dog whistles are by definition avoiding terms with negative associations to the users' opponents. And ["secret police"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_police) are distingushed from undercover cops in general by being specifically for use against political opponents of the regime.

Comment: @Acccumulation The definition of a dog whistle is a term that sounds innocuous to non-believers but carries a clear signal to the believers. "Anglo-saxon values" doesn't make people outside of White Supremacists think of "Aryan". However those who have been "red-pilled" know the White Supremacist version of the history and know what it means.

Comment: But when you say "Aryan", what you mean is "the Nazi conception of the white race". If you want to claim that "Anglo-Saxon" is dog whistle for "the Nazi conception of the white race", that's one thing. But claiming that it's a dog whistle for "Aryan' is engaging in equivocation.

Comment: @Acccumulation Not in this case. The definition of "Aryan" evolved over time before WW2, but ever since it has been considered to be a basic part of Nazi ideology, and the meaning is the one the Nazis used.

Comment: @Accumulation I would in fact say that modern white supremacists in the US use even "Aryan" to denote a racial concept that isn't quite the same as that of the Nazi party of 1930s and 40s.  But they're definitely using "Anglo-Saxon values" to exclude the same people they seek to exclude with the term "Aryan."

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is a critical research failure. Under Nazi terms Slavs or Southern Europeans were being considered as Aryan, just not good enough one. Anglo-Saxons if it was used by Nazi, it was was term for... hostile to them Western Allies.

Answer (score 25):

The term "Anglo-Saxon" is being used in a sense intended to be less obviously discordant than "white" to avoid the obvious association of the movement with White Supremacy, and also to exclude certain people.

It is to some extent a throwback to the conception of a WASP ruling elite in the U.S. which stood for "White, Anglo-Saxon, Protestant" and was coined to distinguish white Catholics (mostly from Ireland and Southern Europe) and white Jews from other whites, despite the fact that the movement in question no longer has a strong bone of contention with white Catholics.

In parts of the U.S., the term "Anglo" is in common usage to distinguish between native speakers of English of European descent, from people who are Hispanic.

"Anglo-Saxon" also seeks to distinguish certain cultural/political traditions that might otherwise be within the scope of "white" such as Middle Eastern and North African people, Jews, and the Communist/Democratic Socialist traditions found in much of Continental Europe.

Comment: Technically, shouldn't Jews be considered a separate ethnic group from Whites because that's how they consider themselves?

Comment: @nick012000 all of the Jews I know consider themselves white.  Do you know many who don't?

Comment: @phoog The Israeli government, for starters.

Comment: @nick012000 you're going to have to provide a little more detail than that if you want to convince me that the Israeli government believes Jews to be "a separate ethnic group from whites."  But even if that were true, it wouldn't imply that Jews in fact _are_ a separate ethnic group from whites.  For starters, "white" is not an ethnic group.

Comment: @phoog "For starters, "white" is not an ethnic group." I'm pretty sure it is, because there are a lot of people who identify as White. It's only polite to refer to someone using the labels that they append to themselves.

Comment: @nick012000 you can "identify as" something that isn't an ethnic group. If some group of ethnic Swedes suddenly declared "we are not white," that would not make it so, regardless of etiquette. It's far more complicated than you're making it out to be.  You still haven't supported your claim about the Israeli government, so I begin to doubt it, but I note that a claim that Jews constitute a distinct ethnicity isn't a claim that they're not white (consider e.g. the Irish, Basque, Flemish, or Polish).  Also consider that Judaism is a religion, so there are e.g. Ethiopian Jews and Ugandan Jews.

Comment: "If some group of ethnic Swedes suddenly declared "we are not white," that would not make it so, regardless of etiquette." For most U.S. government purposes, it would make it so.

Answer (score 8):

As [Paul Johnson points out](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/63572/18471), if speakers don't state their
motivations we can't answer definitively for them. But it does appear to be
an attempt (not for the first time) for American "nativists"† to narrow the
definition of who is the "natural" ruling group for some part of the world.

Similar terms and ideas go back a long way, and were related to determining
just who was and was not properly "white." (The broadly accepted consensus
within "white" groups has changed over time and of course is still disputed
amongst various groups today.)

Robert P Baird, in ["The invention of whiteness: the long history of a
dangerous idea"](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/apr/20/the-invention-of-whiteness-long-history-dangerous-idea) (*The Guardian*, 2021-04-20), writes:

> Thanks to its role in facilitating slavery, whiteness in the US was often
> defined in opposition to blackness, but between those two extremes was
> room for tactical accommodations. In 1751, Benjamin Franklin could claim
> that only the English and Saxons “make the principal Body of White People
> on the Face of the Earth”, and nearly 80 years later, Ralph Waldo Emerson
> would insist that the Irish, like the Chinese and the Native American,
> were not caucasian. Over time, however, the definition of who counted as
> culturally white expanded to include Catholics from southern Europe, the
> Irish and even Jews, who for centuries had been seen as quintessential
> outsiders.

This expansion of who is "white" was of course opposed by some, and
"Anglo-Saxon" became a way to distingish a more narrow definion of who
should belong to the ruling group from the expanding definition of "white."
Adam Serwer goes into detail about this, in ["‘Anglo-Saxon’ Is What You Say
When ‘Whites Only’ Is Too Inclusive"](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2021/04/anglo-saxon-what-you-say-when-whites-only-too-inclusive/618646/) (*The Atlantic*, 2021-04-21):

> ...it helps to understand that “Anglo-Saxon” is what you say when “whites
> only” is simply too inclusive.
>
> The Anglo-Saxonism to which I refer has little to do with the Germanic
> peoples who settled in medieval England. Rather, it’s an archaic,
> pseudoscientific intellectual trend that gained popularity during the
> height of immigration from Eastern and Southern Europe to the United
> States, at the turn of the 20th century. Nativists needed a way to
> explain why these immigrants—Polish, Russian, Greek, Italian, and
> Jewish—were distinct from earlier generations, and why their presence
> posed a danger.
>
> They settled on the idea that the original “native” American settlers
> were descended from “the tribes that met under the oak-trees of old
> Germany to make laws and choose chieftains,” as Francis Walker [put it in
> The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1896/06/restriction-of-immigration/306011/) in 1893, and that the new immigrants lacked the
> biological aptitude for democracy. Anglo-Saxon was a way to distinguish
> genteel old-money types, such as nativist Republican Senator Henry Cabot
> Lodge, from members of inferior races who had names such as, well,
> McCarthy. The influential eugenicist Madison Grant insisted that the
> Irish possessed an “unstable temperament” and a “lack of coordinating and
> reasoning power.”

This eventually did lead to the "Aryan" distinction:

> This belief that America’s “original” population was Anglo-Saxon, and
> that the American way of life was threatened by the presence not just of
> nonwhite people but of inferior, non-Anglo-Saxon (or “Nordic”) white
> people, shaped the racist immigration-restriction laws of the early 20th
> century. As historians have documented, it also influenced [the ideology
> of Nazi Germany](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/04/adam-serwer-madison-grant-white-nationalism/583258/). Translated into law, it produced such
> horrifying artifacts as Virginia’s 1924 anti-miscegenation act, passed
> with the aid of the eugenicist Anglo-Saxon Clubs. The law required all
> babies to be classified as “white” or “colored” and made it a felony to
> “misrepresent” your racial background. The Nazi jurists studying American
> race laws in the 1930s [thought such “one drop” rules](https://www.law.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/upload_documents/Hitler%27s%20American%20Model%20for%20NYU.pdf) were a bit
> too strict.

However, the distinction as made in this case seems to be including groups
that would previously have been excluded from the "Anglo-Saxons" and were
certainly "non-Aryan" (by early 20th century definitions), such as those of
southern European descent. However, though the particular ethnic/regional
groups have changed (as they always do over time), the general exclusionary
intent and its justification has not:

> ...it’s clear that prominent Trumpist officials and intellectuals, some
> of them descended from the very immigrant groups Anglo-Saxon was intended
> to vilify, agree with some of the presumptions of Anglo-Saxonism. The
> echo of the notion that, as Francis Walker wrote, non-Anglo-Saxons are
> biologically incapable of “self-care and self-government” can be heard
> regularly on outlets such as Fox News, where hosts like Tucker Carlson
> argue that [Democrats wish to](https://www.mediamatters.org/fox-news/tucker-carlson-gives-passionate-defense-white-replacement-theory) “replace the current electorate,
> the voters now casting ballots, with new people, more obedient voters
> from the Third World.” This is biological determinism, but it’s also
> simply false. The Republican Party is now led by the descendants of the
> people Walker decried as incapable of self-government, people with
> surnames like Giuliani and Pompeo, even as it launches these old
> calumnies at a new generation of immigrants.

Both articles I've quoted here are well worth reading in full. If you're
short on time, [Serwer's article in *The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2021/04/anglo-saxon-what-you-say-when-whites-only-too-inclusive/618646/) is the shorter
read and more directly relevant to this StackExchange question, but
[Baird's article in *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/apr/20/the-invention-of-whiteness-long-history-dangerous-idea) provides better detail and
historical perspective on the underlying motives and how this all came
about.

---

†"Nativist" here is what the descendants of certain North American
settlers called themselves; they are of course not the earlier natives of
North America whom they conquered and displaced.

Answer (score -1):

The question is based on failing to understand nuance between position on more nationalist right *(something like calling social democrats as Marxists for purpose of political struggle and later wondering why those "Marxists" don't seem to be interested in collectivizing means of production)*

America first, at most would be a **civnat (civic nationalists)**. So yes, they are not specially occupied about someone ethnic origin, as long as he shares their vision and ideology. So a person of different ethnic origin (let's say Roof Korean), while talking about well about the US and wanting to defend his property with AR-15 looks quintessential American, while a White left winger talking badly about US history is clearly an out-group member.

But why Anglo-Saxon? Because the culture is indeed predominantly of Anglo-Saxon origin. There indeed have been plenty of migrants from other European countries, but they adopted language, values and quite often even Protestantism. While that's a subset of Western Culture and they are proud of it, there is clearly hint of US exceptionalism and feeling being above Europe.

If one wants to frame whole phenomena in terms of race (white supremacy, Nazi, etc), then one faces multitude of conundrum why even leader of Proud Boys is a Latino with apparently some Black admixture or why Jewish people like Ben Shapiro seem to be fine.

Comment: “the culture is indeed predominantly of Anglo-Saxon origin” maybe on the 50s, but I think you’d be hard pressed to find any place (even in strongholds like the Hamptons) where WASPs are culturally dominant today.